# sql server 2005/2008 conditional join

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, view

Is there such thing like conditional join:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 A
    IF (a=='TABLE2') THEN INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.item_id=B.id
    ELSE IF (a=='TABLE3') THEN INNER JOIN TABLE3 C ON A.item_id=C.id
```

While a is a field in TABLE1.

I like to use this in stored procedures without using dynamic sql (without writing query as string and EXEC(@query)).

EDIT: I can't write:

```
IF (a=='TABLE2) THEN queryA
ELSE IF (a=='TABLE3') THEN queryB
```

Because a is a field of TABLE1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: Modified answer based on comment below:

You could try to get clever with some left joins. This will return more columns, so you'd probably want to be more discriminating than just `SELECT *`.

```
SELECT *
    FROM TABLE1 A
        LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B
            ON A.item_id = B.id
                AND A.a = 'TABLE2'
        LEFT JOIN TABLE3 C
            ON A.item_id = C.id
                AND A.a = 'TABLE3'
    WHERE (B.id IS NOT NULL AND A.a = 'TABLE2')
       OR (C.id IS NOT NULL AND A.a = 'TABLE3')
```

Comment: @Naor: Modified my answer based on your comment.

Comment: I would add that you probably need to COALESCE some columns from B and C in the output list, since otherwise the caller will need to distinguish between 1) possibly identically named columns and 2) duplicate the branching logic.

Comment: @Cade Roux: +1 That was the point I was trying to make when I said he'd want to be more discriminating than `SELECT *`. Thanks for saying it better than I did.

Comment: @Cade Roux: SELECT * was just an example. @Joe Stefanelli: Question about your solution - Does tsql searches in TABLE2 for metch row although 'a' is equals to 'TABLE3'? or tsql is smart enough to cancel the search in TABLE2?

Comment: @Naor: Yes, that's the purpose of including the check for A.a in the join conditions.

Comment: @Naor Even with specific columns, you are likely going to want to do SELECT COALESCE(B.col, C.col) AS col instead of SELECT B.col AS B_col, C.col AS C_col, because you are not going to want the consumer of the set to duplicate your branching condition.  You can look at the execution plan to see what strategy the database engine has chosen.  In general, this will greatly depend upon your design and choice of indexes.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: I didn't understand from your answer, Does the tsql engine skip TABLE2 without searching for match because it has false inside the ON clause?

Comment: @Naor - the condition stops it from being applied logically in the case an id happens to match, since only one (or neither) branch can be true.  The actual join mechanism chosen to fulfill the query will depend greatly on the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the query as requried:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * 
        FROM TABLE1 A  INNER JOIN TABLE2 B 
            ON A.a='TABLE2' --This will eleminate the table rows if the value of A.a is not 'TABLE2' 
         AND A.item_id=B.id) A,
             (SELECT * FROM
             INNER JOIN TABLE3 C 
            ON A.a='TABLE3' --This will eleminate the table rows if the value of A.a is not 'TABLE3'
            AND A.item_id=C.id 
                ) B
) a
```

Comment: Since A.a cannot satisfy both conditions at the same time, one of your INNER JOINs will fail and the query will return no results. You'd want LEFT JOINs as in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522101/sql-server-2005-2008-conditional-join/4522153#4522153) instead.

Comment: Realized that after clicking on Submit :). Changed the query.